# There are multiple routes for same component, router-outlet is updated perfectly but when i refresh the url then only dashboard graph will load

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular6, app-route

There are multiple routes for same component, router-outlet is updated  perfectly. By default graph was not loaded and when click sidebar also not minimize

But when i refresh the url then only dashboard graph will load? Why is that?

my homepage.html:

```
        <div class="nav-commands">
          <a [routerLink]="['home/dashboard']">People</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['home/second']">Second</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['home/third']">third</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['home/forth']">forth</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['home/fifth']">fifth</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenttext">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
```

my app.route.module.ts:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
  children:[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,},
    { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent,},
    { path: 'third', component: ThirdComponent,},
    { path: 'fourth', component: FourthComponent,},
    { path: 'fifth', component: FifthTaskComponent,},
  ]}
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Because `dashboard` is the default path. That is why it gets loaded, when there is no path found(empty)

Comment: Dashboard Data was not loaded and sidebar also not minimize when redirect to dashboard page, once o refresh the url it will work fine

Comment: *"when i refresh the url then only dashboard graph will load"* - what is the url in the address bar the moment you hit your F5 Key ?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/home/dashboard